# effective way of sending the body as a callback

Tags: node.js, express

In my **app.js**

```
var employees = require('../models/employees');

employees.read(req.params.id, function(body) {
    console.log(body.firstName);
});
```

in my **models/employees**

```
var request = require('request');

var employees = {

    read: function(id, callback) {
        request
            .get('http://api.mysite.com/employees/' + id, function(error, response, body) {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                return callback(body);
            })
    },
};

module.exports = employees;
```

this works. (returns the employee name correctly) but I´m not sure if this is the correct (async) way of getting data from an api and displaying it.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Node.js by default is asynchronous so you don't have to 'make' it work in an async manner.

For future use though, once you have more requests, there may be times where you have to wait for certain request to finish before you can fire the next one off, i.e. run tasks synchronously. In that case you'll have to use something like http://caolan.github.io/async/ and queue function calls in a waterfall/series model.

Comment: what do you mean with 'make' it in an async manner? can you give me an example or tell me what I´m doing wrong in that case?